# NullPointerException When Trying to place Marker on Google Map V2

Tags: android, google-maps, nullpointerexception, google-maps-android-api-2

when I try to place Marker on google map with placeMarker method I get NullPointerException

```
NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference`
I/DpmTcmClient: RegisterTcmMonitor from: org.apache.http.impl.conn.TcmIdleTimerMonitor
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:2
I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 2
D/GoogleCertificates: com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates module is loaded
E/url: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=35.7742618,51.3596331&sensor=true
E/Lat Long to Addresss:
E/Googlemap: null
D/GoogleCertificatesImpl: Fetched 363 Google certificates
I/b: Sending API token request.
E/b: Authentication failed on the server.
E/Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure
Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
                                                                                 Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
```

Also I used getAsyncMap and OnMapReady().Inside  OnMapReady I invoke an Asynktask to get user location and onPostExecute placeMarker Method is invoked:

```
public void placeMarker(LatLongDetails user_latlongobj2,
final Context contextPlace) {


try {
if (googlemap == null) {
    intialiseMap();
    animatecamera(user_latlongobj);
}
if (LoginDetails.Address.length() < 1) {
    LoginDetails.Address = "Getting your location .....";
}
googlemap.clear();
marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
        new LatLng(user_latlongobj2.user_latitude,
                user_latlongobj2.user_longitude)).title(
        LoginDetails.Address);

System.out.println("This is the Address" + LoginDetails.Address);

marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker));


googlemap.addMarker(marker).showInfoWindow();
System.out.println("PLACING MARKER" + LoginDetails.Address);
if (marker == null || contextPlace == null) {
    Intent in =new Intent(this,ProfileActivity1.class);
    in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
    startActivity(in);
}
else
fixmarker(marker, contextPlace);

} catch (Exception e) {
fixmarker(marker, contextPlace);
Log.d("Profileactivity", "" + e);
  } 

}
```

All these problem came along when I tried to change getMap() to getAsyncMap()  Also pls check This [link](https://github.com/Hadisamadbin/Map/blob/master/ProfileActvity) And the complete Whole Activity on [GitHub](https://github.com/Hadisamadbin/Map/blob/master/ProfileActvity)

I removed try and catch to find more details about error.here is logcat:

```
enter code herejava.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
                                                                            at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:87)
                                                                            at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:81)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getResources(AppCompatActivity.java:551)
                                                                            at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:413)
                                                                            at com.example.cabbookinghome.ProfileActivity1.intialiseMap(ProfileActivity1.java:280)
                                                                            at com.example.cabbookinghome.ProfileActivity1.placeMarker(ProfileActivity1.java:327)
                                                                            at epbit.helper.ConversionTaskLatLonLoc.onPostExecute(ConversionTaskLatLonLoc.java:130)
                                                                            at epbit.helper.ConversionTaskLatLonLoc.onPostExecute(ConversionTaskLatLonLoc.java:24)
                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:180)
                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
```

Comment: post your complete logcat.

Comment: I added logcat.

Comment: In logcat along with NLP its also saying E/Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled. Please check in the google console its enabled or not

Comment: @Raghavendra I doubled checked Google Maps Android API is enabled and I dont see any Google Maps Android API v2 to choose !!!

Comment: what is your package name in manifest and build.gradle? both are same?

Comment: yep app Id in build.gradle and package name in manifest both are the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 3 Days Searching and Working on it here is what finally worked.the real problem is googlemap is null which means map is not loaded.I used try and catch but You should never just catch and exception and do nothing. 
after Log the exceptions, check the logs I found this:

```
com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.getMap()' on a null object reference
```

First  I tried This link [Google Map returning nullpointerexception Google Maps Android V2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30116762/google-map-returning-nullpointerexception-google-maps-android-v2)

```
googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

Then getChildFragmentManager become red indicating getChildFragmentManager () cannot be resolved or cannot be referenced.using getSupportFragmentManager() instead as described in this link 
([getChildFragmentManager () cannot be resolved or cannot be referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35090867/getchildfragmentmanager-cannot-be-resolved-or-cannot-be-referenced)) finally solved the problem and map has been loaded

```
googlemap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapfragment)).getMap();
```

Note that if your class extends from `AppCompatActivity`then You need to use `getSupportFragmentManager()`
 because `getChildFragmentManager()` is a method of a Fragment not accessible from`AppCompatActivity`

Answer (score 0):

This is because google map object is cleared after if statement . Remove googlemap.clear() and try.

Comment: Trying that I still have nullPoinetException

Comment: Update your code and the error in the question . I will try to figure it out.

Comment: when I removed googlemap.clear(). I got an extra NLP: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference

Comment: Ok. where did you create the googlemap obejct ? please provide your whole activity .

Comment: I add two linke one for whole activity on github and one for where the exact problem get started

Comment: Make sure your onMapReady(GoogleMap map) is called before using googlemap.

Comment: As you can see in my code the first time googlemap has been used is in intialiseMap() method if googlemap is null then getMapAsync is called.as you know by calling getMapAsync ,onMapReady(GoogleMap map) should have been called

Comment: I removed try and catch to see more details about error and added the logcat

Answer (score 0):

Your map doesn't initialize or not to get your position. Check location sensor is active or not. If not, please active it. You can try this code.

```
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


    }
```

Comment: getMap is depreceted all these problem came along when we try to use getAsyncMap instead